# addCssFile() no longer functions in our app. Is not called and does nothing

Tags: javascript, css, nativescript

Our app is no longer able to use the tns core function addCssFile().  The function is not called at all.

I tried altering one of the addCssFile() calls by calling a made up filename.  It does not trigger any errors and the code seems to skip right over it.  We made no changes to this script but suddenly this function does absolutely nothing.

I added the import addCssFile portion to the code just now, and it says "module has no exported member"

```
  import * as applicationSettings from 'tns-core-modules/application-settings';
  import { localize } from 'nativescript-localize';
  import { ToastDuration, Toasty } from 'nativescript-toasty';
  import { fromObject } from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable';
  import { Page, topmost } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/frame';
  import {addCssFile} from 'tns-core-modules/ui/core/view';

  const source = fromObject({});

  source.set('settingsItems', [
    { name: localize('ColorSchemeMenu.ob'), enabled: true },
    { name: localize('ColorSchemeMenu.bw'), enabled: true },
    { name: localize('ColorSchemeMenu.rw'), enabled: true },
    { name: localize('ColorSchemeMenu.py'), enabled: true }
  ]);

  export function onNavigatingTo(args: any) {
    const page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = source;
  }

  export function settingsItemTapped(args: any) {
    const button = args.object;
    const homePage = button.page.navigationContext.homePage as Page;
    const currentTheme = applicationSettings.getString('theme', 'blue');

    if (button.text === localize('ColorSchemeMenu.ob')) {
      //Orange
      homePage.addCssFile('themes/orange.css');
      applicationSettings.setString('theme', 'orange');
    } else if (button.text === localize('ColorSchemeMenu.bw')) {
      // Blue
      homePage.addCssFile('themes/blue.css');
      applicationSettings.setString('theme', 'blue');
    } else if (button.text === localize('ColorSchemeMenu.rw')) {
      // Red
      homePage.addCssFile('themes/red.css');
      applicationSettings.setString('theme', 'red');
    } else if (button.text === localize('ColorSchemeMenu.py')) {
      // Purple
      //homePage.addCssFile('themes/purple.css');
      homePage.addCssFile('themes/needstofail.css');
      applicationSettings.setString('theme', 'purple');
    }

    console.log('\n\ncolor scheme has been set to: ', applicationSettings.getString('theme'), '\n\n');
    new Toasty(
      `${localize('ColorSchemeMenu.changedMsg')} ${button.text}`,
      ToastDuration.SHORT
    ).show();

    //transition back to settings page after selecting color scheme
    topmost().navigate({
      moduleName: 'home/home-page',
      animated: true,
      transition: {
        name: 'slideRight'
      }
    });

  }


  export function homeBtnTapped(args: any) {
    topmost().navigate({
      moduleName: 'home/home-page',
      animated: true,
      transition: {
        name: 'slideRight'
      }
    });
  }
```

Clicking any of the buttons on the settings page should add the css info to the home page and alter the object colors.  The app recognizes that the buttons are pressed, but no css changes occur.  Manually changing the css file of the home page does alter the appearance of the page.

Comment: Of course it's not an exported member, it's just a private method of View instance, why you would import that?

Comment: @Manoj I am trying anything at this point.  That still doesn't answer my question, why would that method stop working?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not trying to answer but to understand why you would import a method that doesn't exists which might just introduce a TS error. `addCssFile` should work, if you have issues please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: how do i set up a playground, and furthermore how do i do it without giving you the code for the entire app? @Manoj

Comment: You don't have to share anything apart from the required sample code to reproduce the issue, use https://play.nativescript.org/

Comment: here is a playground.  let me know if you need more things
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=McYE7q

Answer (score 0):

You can use application.[addCss](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_application_#addcss) as below by using `file-system`.

```
import * as application from 'tns-core-modules/application/application';
const fs = require('tns-core-modules/file-system');

    if (button.text === localize('ColorSchemeMenu.ob')) {
      //Orange
       pageCss = fs.path.join(fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path, 'themes/orange.css');
       fs.File.fromPath(pageCss).readText().then((res) => {
                application.addCss(res);
            });
      applicationSettings.setString('theme', 'orange');
    } else if (button.text === localize('ColorSchemeMenu.bw')) {
      // Blue

      applicationSettings.setString('theme', 'blue');
    } else if (button.text === localize('ColorSchemeMenu.rw')) {
      // Red

      applicationSettings.setString('theme', 'red');
    } else if (button.text === localize('ColorSchemeMenu.py')) {

      applicationSettings.setString('theme', 'purple');
    }
```